# Proving that a function is NOT a distance on X.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

I have the following question: 
Let $a, b ∈ \mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$, and let X be the collection of real valued functions
defined in $[a, b]$ and bounded, that is:

$X =$ {$f : [a, b] → \mathbb{R}$  such that $f$ is bounded}.

Explain, with an explicit example, why the function
$d(x, y) = \text{max}_{t∈[a,b]}$
$|x(t) − y(t)|$ for every $x, y ∈ X$,
is not a distance on X.

So far, I've gotten that since $f$ is bounded it'd be more appropriate to use

$d(x, y) = $$\text{sup}_{t∈[a,b]}|x(t) − y(t)|$

Since $f$ is bounded a max does not exist but a supremum does and the supremum satisfies all the criteria of a metric space. Is this ok or am I missing something?

Comment: You are essentially correct, if we pass over your enmity for the modal verb *may*.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but you might want to give a counterexample. Thus, consider $d(x,y)$, where 
$$ x = \arctan(\cdot) \qquad \text{and} \qquad y \equiv 0.$$

Comment: Ah, wonderful, that example has made my answer perfect. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad I could help you!